# Best apache caching scheme for files that get refreshed on specific date

Tags: apache

On my website I have some google map overlay images that get updated once per year. So they are candidates for browser caching.

What is the best way of specifying the caching? E.g. if I use ...

`Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"`

(31536000 secs = 1 year)

as far as I understand it this is no use, as if somebody accesses the website one day before I update the images, then they will have to wait one year before they see the correct new images? Can I specify a date when the images will expire rather than a duration. Or is there a better way to handle this?

Also, I cant seem to get the regular expression to work. Can anyone see what could be wrong with this code in my .htaccess file (I want to match all .PNG images in a specific directory) ...

```
<FilesMatch "\/overlayDirectoty\/[^\.]+\.png$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
</FilesMatch>
```

I'm on shared Linux/Apache hosting (goDaddy).

**UPDATE**

The image files have an average size of 580 bytes. But many will be downloaded as the user pans and zooms the map (there are 12000 of them in total).

**UPDATE**

I've just discovered this. If I know I am going to update the images on 1st Jan every year at earliest, will this work? ...

`Header set Expires "Sun, 1 Jan 2014 00:00:00 GMT"`

Comment: IMO you're solving a problem that you don't have (yet).  Your server is already sending `If-modified-since` and `ETag` headers, so you're in good shape.  If you *really* need to avoid getting any traffic between your tile updates then your absolute `Expires` header idea will work--but I'd still be wary of that because it precludes you from updating the tiles sooner (and having previous visitors see the update) if you ever need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you need to do anything at all.

Is Apache already responding with a `Last-modified` header?  (It should be, for static `png` files.)  If so, then browsers should be sending an `If-modified-since` header with all subsequent requests; this will cause your server to reply with an HTTP 304 instead of actually re-sending the image.  (The `ETag` header acts similarly.)

When you do update your files--that one time per year--the file update time will change and all subsequent requests will get the new version of the png file.

The down side of this approach is that every browser will still make a request to your server for each image it's trying to render--so you'll see many 304s in your logs.  But that 304 traffic is (generally) quite minimal when compared with multi-kilobyte image files.

Comment: Thanks for this - I'm understanding things a bit better. It is indeed using `Last-modified`. I notice that there is also a Etag (I'm not setting this - dont know where it is coming from). The average size of the map tiles is only 580 bytes. (Maybe too small to worry about caching?)

Comment: Yes, depending on how many tiles you have (hundreds, thousands, millions?), I wouldn't worry.  A wise programmer once told me, "Premature optimization is the root of all evil." (FYI, ETags will further help your server return 404s instead of the entire image. But  `If-modified-since` should be all you need.)

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would set the image to never expire but then when you do change it, use a different file-name.

Comment: Would work, but this assumes that OP can easily change the HTML source that refers to the images.  Maybe he can, but not sure of that.

Comment: I cant change the image names but I could change the directory that they get stored in - presumably this would trigger a refetch.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to consider whether you want to take advantage of revalidating using etags.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag

You can either let the browser cache the image entirely, or let the client perform a head request that is only used to validate whether the etag is still the same. The e tag is caculated by apache on the fly using file modification time, name and size.

In other words: If your image changes, its e-tag changes.

If the e-tag does not change, the client uses the cacehd version and does not download the file.

However you will have the overhead of a head request, which is minimal and I would recommend this approach.

Nevertheless for completeness lets discuss the other possibilities:

- Change the filename

When the filename changes, the browser will re-fetch it. A common practice is to append a so called "cachebreaker" to the file as a query string. If you generate your src urls in php, just append something like the modification timestamp so the url looks like

> image.jpg?UNIX_TIMESTAMP

- use a caching rule that expires at your point of choosing

I think this is not good to maintain because you nail yourself down as the when refresh the image and you cannot before. But then changing the filename always remains as a measure of "last resort".

You could set the header dynamically using a scripting language and calculate it, however this will be not as performant as delivering using the webserver. There are also combinations like mod_xsendfile, but that would be absolutely overkill for your demand.

No, I think you are not looking at the bigger picture.

mod_expires lets you pecify caching lifetimes in reference to the current time (access) or te file modification. If you make sure your file modification time is correct, just set it inreference to that.

Read up here:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_expires.html

But what you could really do is, just code it!

Its only a header you know, and no one forces you to use mod expires.

Just set the header manually using mod_headers!

Read up here:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_headers.html

I will not cover this with examples because i really think you should use etag.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've read the links but I'm still confused. By 'caching rule' do you mean like the code I used in my example?
Also, in my example I guess I am implicitly using the mod_headers module? Is this what you mean by coding it? Or did you mean somethign in PHP?

Comment: mod_expires uses mod_headers, thats correct. but you can directly set the header with a date of your choosing. like: `Header set Expires "Fri, 01 Jan 2010 00:00:00 GMT"`